# Load XML data with multiple child with same name in Teradata

Tags: xml, xslt, teradata

Below scripts (any one of below two as both gives same output) brings both the daughter's name in same field. However, they are supposed to be in different fields. [

```
Select X.*
FROM(
Select NEW XML(Payload).XMLEXTRACT('/', NULL) TableA
FROM Parents
)C,
XMLTABLE (
'/Father'
PASSING C.TableA 
COLUMNS
"Wife_Name" VARCHAR(20) PATH '/Father/Wife/Name',
"Daughter_Name" VARCHAR(20) PATH '/Father/Wife/Daughter/Name'
)AS X;

SELECT CAST(NEW XML(Payload).XMLEXTRACT('/Father/Wife/Name', NULL) AS VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET UNICODE) AS "Wife_Name",
    CAST(NEW XML(Payload).XMLEXTRACT('/Father/Daughter/Name', NULL) AS VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET UNICODE) AS "Daughter_Name"
FROM Parents;
```

- Current Output (from below script)

Wife  Daughter

Martha   Rani Maya

Expected  Output

Wife  Daughter

Martha   Rani

Martha   Maya

XML File

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
<Father>
    <Wife>
        <Name>Martha</Name>
    </Wife>
    <Children>
        <Daughter>
            <Name>Rani</Name>
            <Age>12</Age>
        </Daughter>
        <Daughter>
            <Name>Maya</Name>
            <Age>16</Age>
        </Daughter>
    </Children>
</Father>
```

Answer (score 0):

Revising the question:

As the XML format shows: both daughters' name should be in different row (not fields).

Above scripts is able to get both the daughters' name is same row separated by space. However, expected output is to get both daughters' names in two different records (rows) with mom's name (Martha) in both the records